# How to design a db that has many 2 many relationship

Tags: core-data, relational-database

It's been a long time since I designed a database and just want to make sure that I am designing it properly.

I have an Entity which has a name and description.

This Entity can have many subEntities which are of type Entity.

So its like a recursive relationship.  Now sure how to design the db properly.

Do I create a second table or what?

Update:  One entity can only have a single parent entity or no parents.

Comment: Should this question be tagged with Core Data? The question refers to tables and the answers are all related to relational databases such as with SQL.

Comment: Not really, because Core Data db design is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: Based on the update to the question, my suggested solution is in bold, below:**

First, let's be clear whether this is really a many-to-many situation because it's not clear from your description whether that's true or not.

You describe a tree structure in which an entity can have "nested" entities and, presumably, those nested entities can each have their own nested entities.  But this is only a many-to-many question if a single entity can belong, simultaneously to multiple parents.

In either case, you will store all the entities in a single table.  **If you want to represent a "simple" tree of nested entities without multiple-parentage then you can add a `parent_entity_id` column to the `entities` table which points to the `entity_id` of the parent.  Top level entities would have either a flag value (for instance, -1) or a `NULL` in this column.**  In this case, you need only one more column and no new tables to represent the relationship.

If it's really a many-to-many relationship with multiple-parentage then you will create a new table `entity_links` with columns `parent_entity_id` and `child_entity_id`.  You manage the relationships by inserting and deleting rows in this table.

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database, you'd use a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_table), end of story.

```
entity
======
id
name
description

xref_entity_subentities
=======================
parent_entity_id (FK references entity)
child_entity_id (FK references entity)
```

---

I can't speak to Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

For a Many-to-Many relationship you'll want an intersection table to delegate the relationships between itself

For Example,

```
Entities       OtherEntities
--------       -------------
ID       ----> EntityID1
Name     <---- EntityID2
Descrip
```

Comment: Yes, but the text describes a tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

For relational databases:
Your entity should not have a sub-entity which is another entity (or the db wont be in normal form) it can contain a relationship (depending on your needs either one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many) to the same table/entity.